# installation of freeglut in visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, github, vcpkg, installation-package

I have tried many ways of installing freeglut in visual studio but it isn't working. I got an solution but i am not getting the idea on how to work with. the solution is this
1. Open powershell. 
2. git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
3. cd .\vcpkg 
4. .\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat 
5. .\vcpkg.exe install openssl 
6. .\vcpkg.exe integrate install After the above steps, you could use the opengl directly in your VS. More info about vcpkg, please see here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg
i am now stuck at step 4 where the command is not working in powershell 
it says

> Blockquote

.\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat : The term '.\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

> Blockquote

what is the issue here? what could be the solution to this?

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you show what you have done and explain how it is not working. That would be a better StackOverflow question.

Comment: I have edited the question. I have mentioned the issue in a detailed manner

Comment: ***what is the issue here?*** You ran that command from the wrong folder. Make sure you change directory in powershell to the folder containing `bootstrap-vcpkg.bat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all to use freeglut you probably want to do:

`.\vcpkg.exe install freeglut` instead of `.\vcpkg.exe install openssl`

If you did that and combined it with `.\vcpkg.exe integrate install` vcpkg will automatically included the `<vcpkgroot>/installed/<triplet>/include` folder to your include folders in VS and link all libraries `<vcpkgroot>/installed/<triplet>/(debug/)lib/` automatically.

Personally I would always suggest to use the CMake toolchain since some preprocess definitions cannot be automatically set.

I would also highly suggest that you read the [documentation](https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/integration/) of vcpkg since those details are also explained there

Comment: Can you give me some info on how to use the CMake toolchain. I am new to this. So a bit confused

Comment: If you project is not using CMake itself there is nothing to do here. If your projects is build using CMake just add the toolchain via -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<pathtotoolchain> to the command line call or set it via the GUI. But that is also explained in the documentation. https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/installing-and-using-packages/