# Visual Studio 2019 Freeglut (via nuget) - cannot open "Freeglut.lib"

Tags: c++, nuget, visual-studio-2019, freeglut

I've been trying to create a GLUT-compatible Visual Studio 2019 project. Manually installing has caused some extremely complicated issues and breaks the project completely (even after uninstalling it) so I'm just trying to use the Nuget package. The .h files seem to be included correctly after this. However, any use of the line '#include <GL/freeglut.h>' - even in a completely blank project - produces an LNK1104 error:

[cannot open file 'freeglut.lib'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DOmP.png)

Are there additional installation steps I'm missing? The .lib file is present in the folders. Trying to manually link it in project properties changes nothing.

Comment: I tried using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61441940/installation-of-freeglut-in-visual-studio-2019) instead. Successfully installed freeglut.lib but now I have an unresolved external symbol error LNK2019.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolved by using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61441940/installation-of-freeglut-in-visual-studio-2019) and then adding the line

`#include <windows.h>`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).